# OBS - Capture frames when recording screen

Tags: c, obs

I'd like to record my whole screen and create images of each frame on the fly in OBS. I would like to record a third-party stream which I receive via web socket and want to extract each frame of the stream during run-time.

I already have a solid overview of the source code (https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) but still have no clue where I should adapt the code.

In the graphics.c file there is this gs_draw_sprite() method which takes the sprite holding the frame and renders it accordingly:

```
void gs_draw_sprite(gs_texture_t *tex, uint32_t flip, uint32_t width,
        uint32_t height)
{
   graphics_t *graphics = thread_graphics;
   float fcx, fcy;
   struct gs_vb_data *data;

   fcx = width ? (float)width : (float)gs_texture_get_width(tex);
   fcy = height ? (float)height : (float)gs_texture_get_height(tex);

   data = gs_vertexbuffer_get_data(graphics->sprite_buffer);
   if (tex && gs_texture_is_rect(tex))
    build_sprite_rect(data, tex, fcx, fcy, flip);
   else
    build_sprite_norm(data, fcx, fcy, flip);

   gs_vertexbuffer_flush(graphics->sprite_buffer);
   gs_load_vertexbuffer(graphics->sprite_buffer);
   gs_load_indexbuffer(NULL);

   gs_draw(GS_TRISTRIP, 0, 0);
}
```

Is there a way to take this sprite and render it to a bitmap? I'm not very experienced in C, unfortunately.

Comment: _"I'm not very experienced in C++"_ Standard c++ doesn't have any notion of image processing or graphics. You probably need some 3rd party stuff to handle that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can stream to a local RTMP server and extract images on the fly with another application. On linux based file system you can try to open the video file that obs writes to.

Comment: @Cubimon Please see my updated description.

Comment: @enne87 do you want each frame on disk or in ram? On disk would fill your disk really fast and requires lot of space and bandwidth if even possible. What are your realtime requirements, you may be interested in some lower level apis that obs use. Otherwise try to get the video from filesystem on linux/try to use the rtmp stream that obs offers.

Comment: @Cubimon I just need the last 20 frames, olders will be removed. So disk space is no mattere here. My only requirement is that the frames have to be in the best possible quality.
Another possibilty would be to extract the frames out of the mp4 that OBS fills during runtime. Is this probably possible with ffmpeg?

Comment: @enne87 mp4 quality varies with video bitrate - if you want best quality you should care for this. OBS has a replay buffer that saves the last x seconds as video file on disk, like a car dash cam/nvidia instant replay - is this your use case? Do you need at every point of time the most recent 20 frames? You can use ffmpeg to extract images from a video, but as I said this doesn't work with all filesystems. On windows the file is blocked from access for other applications until obs closes the file. For a side project I once used gstreamer/ximagesrc on linux with opencv to access the screen.

Comment: @Cubimon Yes I need the most recent 20 frames at every point of time. A big hack but I would be fine with it: Is it possible to save every frame as mp4 in OBS and convert it to an image with ffmpeg?
And by the way: Is it possible in Linux to access the mp4 while it is being created?

Comment: @enne87 I don't think you can save every image as a video file lol. But on Linux you should be able to read the video file while OBS writes into it. Performance may be bad though. But when you are on Linux/X11 you may also take a look at gstreamer/ximagesrc/opencv. But I guess there are also many other ways.

Comment: @Cubimon Alright I'll have a look at this, thank you very much for your support :)